# How do I calculate a one-dimensional index from a multidimensional array? For example two dimensions to one dimension : y * xTot + x = i. But bigger

Tags: arrays, math, multidimensional-array

(This is not a Java specific question, but I write the code snippets in Java code anyway)

Lets say I have a box that has a known width and height. I create a one dimensional array for every index of that box like this:

```
int[] indexes = new int[width * height];
```

Then I want to iterate every value using x and y coordinates like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y != height; y++) 
for (int x = 0; x != width; x++) {
   int index = y * width + x;
   indexes[i] = ...
}
```

This I got no problems with. But when it comes to multi-dimensional arrays where the number of dimension is bigger than 2, is there a formula I could use to calculate the index the same way I did in the above loop?

For example, I got a one dimensional array (based on 4 dimensions):

```
int[] indexes = new int[aTot * bTot * cTot * dTot];

for (int d = 0; d != dTot; d++)
for (int c = 0; c != cTot; c++)
for (int b = 0; b != bTot; b++)
for (int a = 0; a != aTot; a++) {
   int index = ?
}
```

I assume there is some sort of pattern where the index is multiplicatively calculated based on n dimensions. Three dimension should be possible to figure out if I rack my brain on it, but how would I do this with an array with any number of dimensions?
And how would I do the reverse? Like this (but with more dimensions):

```
for (int index = 0; index != width * height; index++) {
  int x = index % width; //(index mod width)
  int y = index / width;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int index = d * aTot * bTot * cTot
          + c * aTot * bTot
          + b * ATot
          + a;

a = index % aTot;
index = (index-a)/aTot;
b = index % bTot;
index = (index-b)/bTot;
...
```